# Importing all csv files within a folder into a cell in Octave

Tags: arrays, csv, import, cell, octave

I have the following code from MATLAB that I am trying to translate to Octave. The goal is to create a cell from all the csv files in the directory folder.

The MATLAB code is...

```
csvfiles=dir('*.csv');
numfiles=length(csvfiles);
celldata=cell(1,numfiles);

for k=1:numfiles
    celldata{k}=csvread(csvfiles(k).name);
end

matrixdata = cell2mat(celldata);
```

However, when I try to run this code in Octave, the celldata contains empty [0x0] entries. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: are you using this script in the same folder as the csv files? this works for me on a toy sample of `.csv` files

Comment: also, what do you mean by "the _directory_ folder"? The words "directory" and "folder" typically mean the same thing. `dir` here is a function that lists al files in a folder (in this case, only `.csv` files). Isn't this what you want?

Comment: @Jennifer: what value has `numfiles` after you ran the code? Btw, you shouldn't use `length`, use `numel` instead

Comment: @Tasos: By "directory", I did mean "folder". Please excuse the confusing language.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for the correction!

Comment: For further clarification, everything seems to work fine until I get to the for loop. Is there something about csvread that is different in Octave from MATLAB?

Comment: There are several questions you need to answer. What OS do you have? What version of octave / matlab? Are you using matlab on windows vs octave on linux by any chance? My guess is that your `numfiles` is 0 for some reason (you can easily debug this). One possible reason is that there are no `.csv` files in the directory you're looking for because the files are case sensitive and your files are actually `.CSV` files in the directory. Windows tends to be non-casesensitive, and linux tends to be case-sensitive. If this isn't helping, you need to give a more specific example I'm afraid.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: As soon as I capitalized '.CSV', it worked! Thank you!